# Affine transformation of a polygon

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]Let A be an affine space in R^3 and there is polygon defined by:

P := {(0, 0, 0) + αe1 + βe2 + γe3, α + β + γ ∈ [0, 1]} ⊂ A.

e1,e2,e3 are vectors from R^3.

I've got problems understanding the definition of P because I thought that a polygon is a plane figure which is spanned by just two vectors, why are there three??
Another question: When I describe a translation (affine transformation) with the vector v=(1,1,1), would the origin of the polygon just be moved from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) or how can I imagine this?

Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: What do the square boxes mean, geometircally?

Comment: do you mean this: α + β + γ ∈ [0, 1] ? I know what it means formally, but I don't know how to imagine this geometrically

Comment: Not that, but (at least at my site) there are little square boxes. After "polygon defined by" in your question you have $P=$ then one square, then $(0,0,0)$ then the linear expression like a dot product, then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ followed by two more little squares, then a capital A. I totally don't know what the boxes are.

Comment: @coffeemath - Looking at editing the question, I see that the last box is supposed to be a "subset" symbol.

Comment: @Blue2001 - Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question legible.

Comment: I added a photo, hope its better now

Comment: Blue: The photo clears up what your question means, but I agree it would be better if done in MathJax as mr_e_man says in his comment.

Comment: @Blue2001 - Why don't you learn how to format equations yourself? Just surround the equation with a pair of dollar signs. Use a backslash for symbols not on your keyboard: "\subset" becomes "$\subset$", "\alpha" becomes "$\alpha$", "0\in\{0\}" becomes "$0\in\{0\}$". Use caret and underscore for subscripts and superscripts: "e_1\in\mathbb R^3" becomes "$e_1\in\mathbb R^3$".

Comment: In an affine space it may be there is a constraint on the three coordinates which would effectively make the thing (span) 2-dimensional. But I'm not up on the correspondence between an affine space and a usual Euclidean space. Maybe another user can clarify...